# GET Response containing png image in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, api, ssjs, encoding

We are using this api (get method): 
https://rapidapi.com/qrcode-monkey/api/custom-qr-code-with-logo

In order to create QR images on the fly when sending emails to our customers from Marketing Cloud.

However, the get request must contain headers in order for it to work. As I understand AMPscript *HTTPGet(1,2,3,4)* function doesn't support headers. So we use instead SSJS function *HTTP.Get(url, headerNames, headerValues);*

The request seems to work. The only problem is that the response contains an image file (image/png).We can't find a way to render the image we got from the response. Please see request and response code below:

**request**:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var url = "https://qrcode-monkey.p.rapidapi.com/qr/custom?data=%25%25%3Dv(%40query)%3D%25%25&config=circle-zebra-vertical";
var headerNames = ["x-rapidapi-host", "x-rapidapi-key"];
var headerValues = ["qrcode-monkey.p.rapidapi.com", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];
var response = HTTP.Get(url, headerNames, headerValues);
Variable.SetValue("@img",response.Content);

</script>                     


%%=v(@img)=%%
```

**response**:

`` ‰PNG  IHDR\\t‘{bKGDÿÿÿ ½§“aIDATxœíÝÁë6@Ñ8H1nBíLQÓŽ›p7?«,îæC¼Pò9ë$Kò ÍÇ¯_¿þøÏßÿ÷{ DQB€ DQB€ DQB€ DQB€ DQB€ DˆVèñx¬:ÔåœÙ;ãÌý¹âqvã=ü9# DQB€ DQB€ DQbÙÚ‡3žÏçq“gü¡×ëõ~¿—jrÁçÿO®Åøä÷ðŒÑ(Çñýý=yÆúúúš|Ìðþž€ DQB€ DQB€ F§9Ÿ19o·} V}öUŸkr‰Ý|ò{h¤„(! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆ¢„(! @l·öá®&×5\ñ\ìÃHQB€ DQB€ DQB€°öá†V­Y°†â3)! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆÛ­}83Oþ“]q=Â™ãìöÜw»žIF @ˆ¢„(! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆUÓ9ÏLe}>ŸÇq,9ÝŒ×ëõ~¿ÿøgWü óÝ®Ù{øßÃ3F£pW«¾`Ž3sœ»Zõ]öï¢„(! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆ¢„(±lß‡OþüUÌÛßç8ŸÌHQB€ DQB€ DQB€Ý÷ar^ú]÷¸ë »]Ï*Wü~)! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆ—Ü÷arnÿäÜõÝ\q…Ýž×ªãL># DQB€ DQB€ DQbÙÚ‡Ý\q}Ä]÷t8ãŠkgVk7F @ˆ¢„(! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆ¢Ä²µ“s¼'ç¥ßuNþ*»­³¸âZƒÝž©‘¢„(! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆ¢„(±Ý¾»­k¸â\úÝ®y·¹ý«¬ºÏ«Ž³ê>)! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆÉµ«ì6—þ®Ÿ}·Ï5¹/Ænë&)! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆËö}ØmÎùä¾»ÍÛ_e·g:y®É=Av{7Œ€ DQB€ DQB€ Dˆeû>LÚm®øM®é8c·ý,îúÙÏ0RB€ DQB€ DQB€ –­}˜ümÿÝ®yržü*»Ííßíþœ±ÛçZõ½0RB€ DQB€ DQB€ þYu Ý~»þŒO¾æ+î±ÛÞ«ìvŸ€ DQB€ DQB€ Dˆek®ø»ý«¬š»¾Û~“û>¬2¹¦cò>OÞC# DQB€ DQB€ DQbÙÚ‡3žÏçq“gü¡×ëõ~¿—êÌÜõÝöX5'·Ï5y®É{¸ê³Fá8ŽïïïÉ3þÐ×××ª(ÀUø÷QB€ DQB€ DQbtšów'¿ÛøÝîó™ë¹âÞ"»­k8ÃHQB€ DQB€ DQB€ØníÃ]Yð{«æöï¶ŽàŒÝÖG)! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆÖ>läŠsò'­Zgq×½3V1RB€ DQB€ DQB€ ¶[û°Û|ûI“{(LÎÿ¿ë3Ým}Ä*F @ˆ¢„(! @ˆ¢„(! @ˆUSPÏLç|>ŸÇq,9ÝŒ×ëõ~¿ÿøg“÷ðŒ»Ns¾âOªO>ÓUF£pWWœ?yÍÞ±«î³€ DQB€ DQB€ Dˆek€{0RB€ DQB€ DQB€ DQB€ DQB€ DQB€ þ^*æu*ƒ“ÅIEND®B`‚ ``

It seems to return the image in the wrong encoding. Also the response seem to be cropped (maybe because of the use of the *Varible.SetValue* function?). Does anyone had luck with getting a get response which contains img in Marketing Cloud? Thanks

Comment: have you tried displaying it inside an img tag? e.g. `<img src="%%=v(@img)=%%" />`?

Comment: @Gortonington yes, this results in an empty image. ```<img src=" " / >```

Comment: Maybe base64 encode it then use data URI scheme to put it inline in an img tag

<img src="data:image/png;base64,%%=v(Base64Encode(@img))=%%" />